# How to display VAST ads in my android app?

Tags: android, ads, vast

I would like to display video Ads in my app based on VAST. Can anybody please guide me on how to do that ?

Comment: did u manage to find it out ?

Comment: @sasikt Not yet. Actually we left that plan. It was for a client. They switched to Google ads.

Comment: I'm trying the same now with no luck :D thanks :)

Comment: I think that using Google IMA sdk for android should get the job done.
https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/android/quickstart

Answer (score 6):

You can use any VAST ad supporting advertising SDK for showing VAST video ads.

OR

You can parse the VAST response in you application then you can play the video link in Android native video player.
In this case you also have to fire all VAST ad tracking events.

Comment: can you give some details on how we can parse the VAST response?

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question, but for anyone looking at it lately - **[THIS](https://github.com/nexage/sourcekit-vast-android)** is a nice VAST container by Nexage. Integration is super easy and it works pretty good, the only drawback is that it's adding a huge library to your project (unnecessary huge), which might be a problem for big projects hitting the DEXOPT limit problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Daily Motion Client** https://github.com/dailymotion/vast-client-js
IMHO, it's easiest way to parse VAST response. Add the parser to html and implement simple video player with data that provides parser. Show result html page in WebView, also you can use javascript interface to pass parameters from Java to javascript in html.

**Google Interactive Media Ad** https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/android/?hl=ru it's difficult to integrate the sdk to show only vast ad without content.

**Nexage VAST SDK** https://github.com/nexage/sourcekit-vast-android
(has huge library for validation, but source is opened and it's easy to change this to the javax.xml.validation.Validator)

They can request ad by network tag, shows loaded ad and track users actions.

It is called c2s integration (client to server).

Comment: In July 2022 Google Interactive Media Ad is easy to integrate. The "content" can be a 0 seconds length video placed in assets folder.